# how to get the id from database?

Tags: php

this is my news.php ... This code will show the title, and some news contents. When you click the title, it must get the ID and directs you the article. But mine was not getting the ID.

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php';
?>

<?php
$qry = (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles"));?>
<newslist title="Latest News">
<?php   
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
        { ?>

        <news category="green" url="asdf.php?id="<?php echo $row['id']?>"" date="<?php echo $row['date']?>">
         <headline><?php echo "<h1>".$row['title']."</h1>";?></headline>
        <detail><?php echo "<p>".substr($row['content'],0,60)."..."."</p>"; ?> </detail>
          </news>

        <?php 
        }?>



</newslist>
```

This is the javascript code fragment that(i guess) was processing the URL code above. Was the problem exists in the javascript code? (vscroller.js)

`var url = $(this).attr('url');
                            var htext = $(this).find('headline').text();
                            description.append($('<h1/>').html("<a href='" + url + "'>" + htext + "</a>"));`

This is my asdf.php. This is the destination when you click one article.

```
    `<?php

     $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles");
     if(!$qry)
     {
     die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
     }
     ?>

     <div id="content">
     <?php
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
     {
     ?>
        <p class="head">Posted In: <?php echo $row['category'];?></p>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <h1><?php echo $row['title'];?></h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p class="meta"><?php echo $row['date']." "."Written By: ".$row['author'];?>
        </p>
        <div id="article" class="article">
        <p class="intro">
        <?php echo "<img src=".$row['image']."/>"."<p>".$row['content']."</p>";?></p>
        <div class="line"></div><br /><br />

    <?php
    }
    ?>

<p id="pc_reference" class="meta"><a href="demo.php">Back to News Page</a></p>
        </div>`
```

this code is from the page where i display the news.php(main.php)

```
    `<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#vscroller').vscroller({ newsfeed: 'news.php' });
     });
     </script>

    <html>
    <body>
    <div class="news-wrapper" id="vscroller"></div>`
```

the original source for this can be found at http://www.egrappler.com/xml-driven-vertical-news-scroller-script-using-html-and-jquery-vscroller/

Comment: Please cut/paste an example of the actual HTML (with "<news category" and "id=xyz") that's being sent to the browser.

Comment: This is not a HTML Tags or if you get url then you must have to assign id in any tags like this <div id= "url">url....</div>

Comment: @iheartLUHAN: please cut/paste some example HTML you generated from the PHP.  That will absolutely help us debug what the Javascript should be doing.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @tereško - Horse crap ;)  I'll take nice, simple, reliabe mysql_* over an ORM du jour any day, thank you please :)

Comment: @paulsm4 , PDO is not an ORM. It is database connection abstraction. See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: @paulsm4 i've edited my code. is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to make sure that you really have a row named id in your database.

Try this code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query));
print_r($row);
```

So you can verify the fields

Comment: yes. im sure there is a row named ID. i've verified it many times.

Answer (score 1):

As you say you have verified the ID column exists, the next step in my opinion would be to

check that this snippet `echo $row['id']` is returning the expected data.

Once you have confirmed that, please output an example HTML code source if it is still wrong.

As paulsm4 says we need to see the HTML output so we can help debug what/where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

```
      <?php include 'connect.php';?>  
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $a[] = $row;
            foreach($a as $key=>$value){
                $array[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        ?>
        <?php foreach($array as $a):?>
        <news category="green" url="asdf.php?id="<?php echo $a['id']?>"" date="<?php echo $a['date']?>">
                 <headline><?php echo "<h1>".$a['title']."</h1>";?></headline>
                <detail><?php echo "<p>".substr($a['content'],0,60)."..."."</p>"; ?> </detail>
         </news>
        <?php endforeach;?>
```

I have rearrange the array so it will print much better.