# How to retrieve articles from database without the html tags

Tags: php

I am using an editor(ckeditor) and articles created there were saved in the database as a formatted article including the html tags.

Now, i want to retrieve that article without getting the html tags,
but the articles that i must retrieve are the ones that is already formatted.

Can anyone share the idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) to remove HTML tags from a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP function `strip_tags()` to do that, here is the link:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

> strip_tags($article);

EDIT: But before you do that you may want to replace all the `<br>` tags with a new line character, `\n` by using something like this function

```
 function br2nl($article) 
 {
     return preg_replace('/\<br(\s*)?\/?\>/i', "\n", $article); 
 }
```

Comment: ok. i have another problem . here's the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963926/how-to-get-the-id-from-database